# Fixed expandable navigation bar on mobile website

Tags: css, mobile, css-position, navigationbar

I want to have a **fixed navigation bar** on a mobile website. So far, I'm trying to do so by setting `position: fixed` to the navigation bar. **PLUS** My navigation bar is expandable, so the div below has to react to the height of the navigation bar. I want the div below to stay scrollable.

1) `#bar{position: fixed}` and `#content{}`

[image: only having position: fixed on the bar]

2) `#bar{position: fixed}` and `#content{position: relative; top:58px;}`

[image: having top: 58px on the div below]
[image: doesn't help when the bar expands]

**EDIT** Here's some of my code.

```
<div id="navigation">
   <div id="icons" class="mobile">
      <img alt="Logo Header" src="res/logo_small_w.png"/>
      <img id="menu_icon" alt="Menu Logo" onclick="menu()" style="float:right;" src="res/menu_icon.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="menu_items">
      <h2>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openNext()">Nächster Hotspot</a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openTermine()">Termine</a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openBerichte()">Berichte</a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openFeedback()">Feedback</a>
      </h2>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
   <div id="load_container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation {
   box-shadow:      0px 2px 2px #005b00;
   position:        fixed;
   left:            0px;
   right:           0px;
}

#content {
   position:    relative;
   top:         58px;
}

.menu_items {
   display:         none;
   width:           100%;
}

.menu_items a {
   border-top:          1px solid grey;
   color:               inherit;
   display:             block;
   padding-bottom:      5px;
   padding-top:         5px;
   text-align:          center;
   text-decoration:     none;
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to help you if you don't supply us with some of your code.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nav-bar it might be something you could use